# Permission denied to create tree directory - El Capitan

Tags: terminal, macos

Following this [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) , under the subtitle

> Download angular-phonecat

Since there is a local server comes packages with El Capitan, and I have an ios emulator installed to run some web app while developing, my best "guess" is that I need to place my WebApp projects where the server limits me to

While running as a user, I need to git clone a dir tree in a folder which belongs to the admin.

As requested by a commenter to show the full path of the destination folder:

The destination folder where the tree will be copied to is:
Macintosh HD/Library/WebServer/Documents/

[image]

In the terminal, If the destination folder gives rwx to the admin then why "permission denied" is returned?

I don't want to add the user to the sodoers file and do not want to logout and login as an admin as the command I copied form a web page unto the clipboard will be lost. Thanks

```
~$ su <admin-name>
Password:
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ cd ../../Library/WebServer/Documents/
bash-3.2$ git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'angular-phonecat': Permission denied
bash-3.2$ ls -la
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   wheel    238 10 Jan 07:26 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   wheel    170 23 Aug 09:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel   3726 23 Aug 09:53 PoweredByMacOSX.gif
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel  31958 23 Aug 09:53 PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
-rw-rw-r--   1 root   admin     44 21 Nov  2004 index.html.en
-rw-r--r--   1 root   wheel     45 12 Jun  2007 index.html.en~orig
bash-3.2$ 

bash-3.2$ ls -la ../
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170 23 Aug 09:53 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 66 root  wheel  2244 13 Nov 03:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136 23 Aug 09:53 CGI-Executables
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel   238 10 Jan 07:26 Documents
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel   102 23 Aug 09:53 share
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: whoever down voted it, care to comment why or what improvement could be made to this question for beginners in OSX to learn?

Comment: What is the full path of the directory you are trying to write to?

Comment: Where does the tutorial say this needs to be in a directory not in your home directory and not as you?

Comment: The destination is chosen by me since that is where the local web server is, so that in the browser url I can type "http://localhost:63342/<project folder>/index.html" and expect it to work.

Comment: My last comments was meant to open the index.html not in the browser but in a ios emulator for web app development.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the directory you are in can only be written to by root - first line in `ls -la`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   wheel    238 10 Jan 07:26 .
     ↑  ↑ 
     |  | everyone (except root) can't write
     | members of the wheel group (except root) can't write
```

I do not understand why the git is cloned to an admin user? Why not just in your name clone to a directory in your own home directory.

Noting your comment re beginners we need to know more as to experienced users this looks like you are doing something totally wrong i.e. explain the process you need to be doing from the start.